# Exercise 22.6 in Humphreys Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am having trouble with this problem and the referred exercise 13.12.

Here is the statement of the exercise along with the screenshot of the table below:
For $L$ of type $G_2$, use Table 2 of (22.4) to determine all weights and their multiplicities for $V (λ), λ = λ_1 + 2λ_2$. Compute dim $ V (λ) = 286$. [Cf. Exercise 13.12.]

My initial understanding was to look at row (12), but the sum of dimensions is not 286. How one goes about this computation? Does one need to compute the orbit of (12) under the Weyl group? If yes, how does one do it and use it to compute the dimension?

Can one use the Weyl Dimension formula where $\lambda=m_1λ_1 + m_2λ_2$?
$$\dim V(\lambda) = 1/120 (m_1+1)(m_2+1)(m_1+m_2+2)(m_1+2m_2+3)(m_1+3m_2+4)(2m_1+3m_2+5)$$

[image]

Comment: This table is only showing the multiplicities of _dominant_ weights. You need to multiply the multiplicity of each dominant weight by the size of its Weyl group orbit: either 1, 6, or 12, depending on whether the weight has two, one, or no zeroes when expressed in the fundamental basis.

Comment: How can one compute these Weyl group orbits for G_2? My understanding is that Weyl group is the Dihedral group of order 12 generated by rotations pi/3 and horizontal reflections. In general, how can one determine the weights in the orbits, if one knows the fundamental weights in terms of simple roots? And what do you mean by having zeroes in terms of the fundamental basis?